# How to retrieve user image in FQL selected comments from stream?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm building a simple `FQL` module to pull in comments from any Facebook fan page.

Getting the post_id, message, actor_id seems pretty straightforward.

However the stream documentation does not seem to indicate any way to get the avatar and name.

What I'm doing is:

```sql
SELECT post_id, message, actor_id
FROM   stream
WHERE  source_id = 125938460770575
```

Which returns FB Id, comments and the post itself.

I need the user info as well to go along with this.

The obvious solution is to just to an extra `FQL` API call for every single FB Id (actor_id) that appears to get this info, but I assume there is a better way to do it.

Can I please get some hints on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an *FQL Multi-Query* to achieve that – you “name” your queries, and then the second query can refer to values (in this case the user ids) the first query fetched.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/#multi has an example that is very similar to what you want, except for that it looks up the user names and pics for users attending an event – but to rewrite that for what you want should be no big deal.

Afterwards you only have to match the ids you get for the users commenting on something with the ids from the second query while processing/displaying the data.

Answer (score 0):

> The obvious solution is to just to an extra FQL api call for every single fb id (actor_id) that appears to get this info, but I assume there is a better way to do it.

Yes of course, you can do it like this-

```sql
SELECT uid,
       pic,
       first_name,
       last_name
FROM   user
WHERE  uid IN(
       SELECT post_id,
              message,
              actor_id
       FROM stream
       WHERE source_id = 125938460770575)
```

Fetch any detail of the [user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/)